# Copying object from nested hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the 2 following hashmaps where `Message` is an object i created.

```
HashMap<String, Message> hmA = new HashMap<>(); //A
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Message>> hmFinal = new HashMap<>();
```

If i populate `hmA` with the following

```
hmA.put("Albert", new Message("Albert", "albert@hotmail.com", "122-4645 ));
hmA.put("Anthony", new Message("Anthony", "anthony@hotmail.com", "570-5214"));
hmA.put("Alphonso", new Message("Alphonso", "alphonso@hotmail.com", "888-5314"));
```

Then I add `hmA` to `hmFinal`

```
 hmFinal.put("A", hmA);
```

Now if I create a temp hashmap

```
HashMap<String, Message> tempHM =  new HashMap<>();
```

How could I copy the entire hashmap `hmA` to `tempHM` using `hmFinal` if I only had the  letter A to search with?

Basically, if a user wants to see the hashmap associated with the letter A, I want to be able to grab all of `hmA` and search through the info in it.

Comment: Ahh hash maps of hash maps. So long OOP 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you're looking for is [putAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)):

```
HashMap<String, Message> tempHM =  new HashMap<>();
tempHM.putAll(hmFinal.get("A"));
```

Answer (score 3):

After retrieving the map by searching using the letter A, use [`putAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) to copy all entries to the map:

```
HashMap<String, Message> mapA = hmFinal.get("A");
tempHM.putAll(mapA);
```

**P.S.**: Try to program variables using the interfaces (`Map` instead of `HashMap`).